# Access-Control-Allow-Origin getJSON Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, cors

I have some code that works fine in **development**.

**ORIGINAL CODE**

```
respond_to :json

def index
  @tags = current_user.tags
  respond_with(@tags.map{|tag| {:id => tag.id, :name => tag.name} })
end
```

with a route file of

```
get "tags/index"
```

and my jQuery file has a line like this

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/tags.json', function(data) {
```

However, when pushing it to **production**  I get an error
XmlHttpRequest error: Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. After doing some research

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828982/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-an-url-with-jquery)
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120937/handling-jsonp-in-rails-3-controller)
and 
[Here](http://www.tsheffler.com/blog/?p=428)

I changed my code to this

**NEW CODE**

```
def index
  @tags = current_user.tags
  respond_to do |format|
    if params[:callback]
      format.json { render :json => @tags.map{|tag| {:id => tag.id, :name => tag.name}   }.to_json , :callback => params[:callback]}
    else
      format.json { render :json => @tags.map{|tag| {:id => tag.id, :name => tag.name} }}
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/tags.json' + '&callback=?', function(data) {
```

with the same route.

What is going on here? I'm still getting the same error, why didn't the callback fix it?

**all jQuery Code**

```
  var items = [];
  var prepopulate = [];

  $(function () {
     var myVarsJSON = $("#my_vars_json").html(),
          myVars     = $.parseJSON(myVarsJSON);
        $.each(myVars, function(i, obj) {
          return prepopulate.push(obj.name);
          });

    $.getJSON('/tags.json' + '&callback=?', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
            return items.push(obj.name);
            });
     $("#article_tag_ids_edit").val(prepopulate).select2({
      width: "element",
      tags: items,
      tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
      });
    });
  });

  $.getJSON('/tags.json' + '&callback=?', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
            return items.push(obj.name);
            });

      $("#article_tag_ids").select2({
      width: "element",
      tags: items,
      tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this out

instead of

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/tags.json' + '&callback=?', function(data)
```

use this

```
$.getJSON('/tags.json' + '?callback=?', function(data)
```

Comment: @ebbflowgo if you are checking in production environment, clean and recompile all your assets.

Comment: I now get a new error. GET url.com/tags.json&callback=jQuerysomthing 406 (Not Acceptable)

Comment: Hi Sachin Singh, I have posted it above

Comment: @ebbflowgo use '?callback=?' instead of '&callback=?' in your code.

Comment: Sachin Singh, I get the same GET 406 error. However, when I plug the tags.json?callback=? into the URL I do get the json populating which is a good sign. As a side note, when I do ?callback=? there is a '?' before the JSON so I think it's better to have ?callback=

Comment: @ebbflowgo clean and recompile the assets again.

Comment: thanks very much it works now! As a side note, what's the best way to clean and recompile for heroku production? I did it several ways, on my local drive using heroku run rake assets:clobber; heroku run rake assets:precompile; and then on my local drive I did RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile, after which I committed it..