# Getting html response from jsonp ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jsonp

I'm curious as to why with this ajax call:

```
   $.ajax({
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/gwsearch/ajax_search?d1=36354&d2=36355',
      crossDomain: true
  }).done(function(data){
    alert(data);
  });
```

To this rails method:

```
    def ajax_search
     #random code
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js { render :json => @gw_search_results.to_json, :callback => params['callback'] }
     end
```

I am getting an html response.  If I remove the "format.html" I get a jsonp response back with the correct data, but I am just curious as to why rails is choosing to send back html by default, instead of jsonp?  What am I missing?  I thought with  a js call, it shoots back a js response if available?

Comment: Did you check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120937/handling-jsonp-in-rails-3-controller

Comment: also, read this:-
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637522/controller-can-not-detect-ajax-requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, for those wondering, the order of your respond_to statements does indeed matter.  I did not think they did.  This yields me a json response:

```
    respond_to do |format|
      if params[:callback]
        format.js { render :json => {:items_by_tag => @gw_search_results.to_json}, :callback => params[:callback] }
      else
        format.json { render json: {:items_by_tag => @gw_search_results}}
       end
    format.html
    end
```

It seems to hit the jsonp callback conditional and spit me back what I need, where as before, I had

```
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
      if params[:callback]
        format.js { render :json => {:items_by_tag => @gw_search_results.to_json}, :callback => params[:callback] }
      else
        format.json { render json: {:items_by_tag => @gw_search_results}}
       end
    end
```

I'm guessing it saw the format.html as a valid response and yielded that response instead of the json.  Note that even when I changed the request headers on the ajax call to "application/json" I still was getting an html response back with the problematic code I have showcased at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

http://davidwparker.com/2010/03/09/api-in-rails-respond-to-and-respond-with/

There needs to be an explicit respond to and respond with statement.

Comment: I have respond_to :html, :json at the top of the controller before any methods and this below at the end of the method, still getting an html response unless I remove format.html.  I want to dictate from the request that I want a json response, how can I do this?


 respond_with do |format|
      format.html
       if params[:callback]
         format.js { render :json => {:items_by_tag => @gw_search_results.to_json}, :callback => params[:callback] }
       else
        format.json { render json: {:items_by_tag => @gw_search_results}}
       end
      end